# Can't change width of flyout

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a flyout has id "productFlyout". I tried to set its background color and width. It has red color but the width doesn't change. It seems that Metro doesn't allow width too big.

JS file:

```
productFlyout.winControl.show(dummyDOM, "bottom", "center");
```

CSS file:

```
#productFlyout {
   background: red;
    width: 1000px;
}


#productFlyout .win-flyout {
    width: 1000px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: If you use DOM explorer in VS, does it say who is setting the width, and which rule is setting it? I *might* be that the flyout is setting is programmatically and there for has a higher specificity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are limits for Flyout set by default.  Do a quick search for ".win-flyout" in either ui-dark.css or ui-light.css and you'll see defaults for:

- min-width
- max-width
- min-height
- max-height

You can override those in your CSS, but keep in mind the guidance for Flyouts is to keep them as small as possible.  See "Designing a Flyout" in this article:

["Guidelines & checklist for Flyouts"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465341.aspx#designing_a_flyout)